# One of the main ideas of this text

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, phrase-request

There is a chunk of text which can be summarized in one or more ideas. The idea is used as something that you learn, by reading that text.

What is a word or what would be the best way of saying: one of the ideas of this text...

I was thinking it could be something like: "One of the highlights.."

Answer (score 1):

You could say

> One of the **points** [covered | addressed | explained | raised] in this [chunk of text]

Is the chunk a chapter? a paragraph?   a section?

Answer (score 1):

> - One of the concepts described in this section is X.
> - One of the ideas explained in this chapter is X.
> - One of the points covered in this paragraph is X.
> - One of the thoughts expressed in this essay is X.
> - One of the features covered in this text is X.

"raised" could also work as a verb here. The various verbs have slightly different meanings, but each of them could apply to things learned in a particular section of text.